# Correct ActiveRecord association for a reference table?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relational-database

Given two models:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_status

end

class UserStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :descr
end
```

The user.user_status column is intended to be a single ID which can be used to join against UserStatus for additional information, such as status icon and description.

UserStatus is a read-only reference table which will have very few rows, all unique.  Let's say it has only four rows:

```rb
{ :id => 0, :descr => 'New' },
{ :id => 1, :descr => 'Banned' },
{ :id => 2, :descr => 'Active' },
{ :id => 3, :descr => 'Unverified' }
```

Should I bother with ActiveRecord associations for reference tables?  If so, what is the proper ActiveRecord association if I want to (or must) store the associated UserStatus ID in the user table?  From what I can tell, based on the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), 'User belongs_to :user_status' is my best bet, but linguistically this is failure; because a User does not "belong to" a status, a user is in a state or has a status.  Or is this just too hair-splitting of me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongs_to` doesn't always make linguistic sense, but in this case it's just what you want.

```
UserStatus has_many :users
User belongs_to :user_status
```

Which also allows the status to find all users in that state, which can be useful.

```
naughtyPeople = UserStatus.where(descr: 'Banned').users
```

What's more important, linguistically, is the API you settle on to get this data.

```
User.find(123).user_status.descr
```

That kind of sucks. It has the relations you want, but the API is pretty verbose.

```
class User
  def status
    user_status.descr
  end
end

User.find(123).status
```

Much better.

Or even possibly this!

```
class User
  def status
    user_status.descr
  end

  def status=(status_string)
    self.user_status = UserStatus.where(descr: status_string).first
  end
end

user = User.find(123)
user.status = 'Banned'
user.user_status #=> { id: 3, descr: "Banned" }
```

How far you want to massage it is up to you.